# JYTHON/PYTHON - raw_input losing first character of string

Tags: python, string, character, jython, raw-input

I am reading in a name as you will see below, however regardless of what you type in it loses the first character, for example, 'Bob' will become 'ob'. Because of this I cannot compare the user's input to what they are searching for, breaking the entire program.

```
def Find() :
  global AddressBookAll
  Success = false  
  PersonToFind = str(raw_input("\nEnter the nickname of the person you would like to find: "))
  for x in AddressBookAll :
    if(x == PersonToFind) :  
      success = true
      printNow("\n%s" %(x))
      for y in AddressBookAll[x] :
        printNow("%s" %(y))
  if(Success == false) :
    printNow("\nNot Found.")
```

Comment: Lowercase `false` and `true`? Is this real code?

Comment: Try to remove `str` from `str(raw_input(...))`. `raw_input` already returns a string, so adding a `str` call you probably get an unexpected name. However I don't see how this single piece of code could produce the behaviour you claim.

Comment: What observable behavior causes you to say the input loses its first character? What's `printNow`?

Comment: Python is case sensitive, `Success` and `success` is not the same thing, also `true` should be `True`.

Comment: You've written `Success` in two places and `success` in a third, so `Not Found` will always print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First, you shouldn't be using a global variable. It would make much more sense to pass the address book to your function. Don't worry, only a reference will be passed, so it's cheap.

Second, function names (and other variable names except classes) should be lowercase.

Third, no need to call `str()` on `raw_input()` which already returns a string.

Fourth, use the `.format()` string syntax instead of `%` string formatting.

Fifth, `x` appears to be a string from `AddressBookAll` (that's a guess because you're comparing `PersonToFind` to it). Let's hope `AddressBookAll` is a dictionary, otherwise `AddressBookAll[x]` will fail.

Sixth, if a single character is dropped anywhere, it must be in `printNow()` which you haven't shown to us. There is no other place in your code where something like that could happen.

Seventh, case matters. `True` is not the same as `true`. Neither are `Success` and `success`.

Eighth, Python is not Java. `if` doesn't need parentheses, for example.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your quick feedback. Although everything you say is true, this is just a single semester paper and we haven't even touched upon things such as using .format() etc. I took your advice and fixed up some casing because it did look out of place. As for the error, it was the '\n' character at the start of the "raw_input". It was sticking in the buffer or something and replacing the first character of whatever I typed in! And I'm not actually doing Python, it's been dubbed Jython because it is a hybrid of the two languages, I much prefer C haha, thanks again!

Comment: Sure, Jython still uses Python syntax, though, so the points still stand.

Comment: Indeed they do, you've been very helpful! It's been a hard paper because the lecturer has very limited knowledge on the topic, I think she was learning it alongside us. I imagine a few of my syntax errors are due to me having only programmed in C before, such as using parentheses for if statements. Anyway, thanks again mate. :-)